# Solution verification: If the Hamiltonian of a dynamical system is given by $H=pq-q^2,$ then what happens to the value of $p$ and $q$ as $t\to\infty$

Tags: solution-verification, classical-mechanics

**Problem:** Let the Hamiltonian of a dynamical system is given by $~H=pq-q^2~,$ where $~q~$ is the generalized co-ordinate and $~p~$ is the generalized momentum. Then as $~t\to\infty~$

$1.~~~q\to\infty~,~~p\to\infty$
$2.~~~q\to0~,~~p\to0$
$3.~~~q\to\infty~,~~p\to0$
$4.~~~q\to0~,~~p\to\infty$

**My work:** We know that [the time evolution of the system is uniquely defined by Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics):  $$\dfrac{dq}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p}\qquad\text{and}\qquad-\dfrac{dp}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dq}{dt}=q\qquad\text{and}\qquad\dfrac{dp}{dt}=-p+2q$$Integrating,
$$q=Ae^t\qquad\text{and}\qquad p=Ae^{2t}+Be^{-t}$$where $~A~,~B~$ are arbitrary constants.

Now when $~t\to\infty~,$ then $~~~q\to\infty~,~~p\to\infty~.$ 
Hence only option $(1)$ is true.

**My query:** But given that only correct option is option  $(2)$. But How (? ) which I am not able to understand. Is there any problem in my work ? Please help.

Comment: Note that $\dot H = 0$ but $\frac{d}{dt}(A e^t \left(A e^{2 t}+B e^{-t}\right)-A^2 e^{2 t})\ne 0$

Comment: How can you say that $~\dot H = 0~$ ?

Comment: Because $\dot H = p\dot q+q\dot p-2q\dot q$ but $\dot p = -(p-2q)$ and $\dot q = q$ so after substitution we have $\dot H =0$

Comment: Great, but how you relate your point with the answer of  my question ? Can you specify please ?

Comment: If $p = Ae^{2t}+Be^{-t}$ and $q=A e^t$ then $\dot H \ne 0$

Comment: Yes, now I got your point. So my solution (explanation) is incorrect. Now I am completely in the dark, please provide the correct answer with proper explanation. Please.